# Mailchimp's ckeditor, limiting design options in the editor

Tags: ckeditor, html-email, mailchimp

I would like to limit the design options in the ckeditor that Mailchimp offers in editable content area's. For instance I would like to disable `Text Color`, `Background Color`, Alignment, etc.

See in this screenshot the default CKeditor that Mailchimp offers.
[image: screenshot of the Mailchimp CKeditor]

My question: does anyone know if this is possible at all within Mailchimp? And if so, how could it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I think calling mailchimp support would likely be the best way to get this info - but I am going to guess that it is a no.

Your best bet is instead of disabling, setting an "!important" declarative to whatever style you want displayed so it overwrites whatever is chosen in the editor. This would need to be done in a style tag and then also inline on the p or td or span or whatever tag you inline your styles on in the template.

It is a lot of extra code and is not guaranteed to work 100% but is really only solution I can think of.

In the editor screen it will likely still show whatever they input but once it goes into the template the CSS should override it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After searching a little bit, I also think it's a definitive NO. Didn't find info about this anywhere. I understand the `!important` override structure, but that would in turn conflict with other styles I have, a minefield I'm not entering. Guess I'll just have to instruct the people who are going to work with the template thoroughly :)

Comment: Outside that the only other option I can think of is building a custom editor that uses an SDK or API call to store the content in Mailchimp (not even sure if Mailchimp has this as an option)